# WooCommerce simple ticketing system at product level

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I am using WordPress and WooCommerce and have an SQL query to call meta tags for a specific product type.

```
function get_last_order_id_from_product( $product_id ) {
global $wpdb;

return $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT oi.order_id
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as oi
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as oim
        ON oi.order_item_id = oim.order_item_id
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as oim2
        ON oi.order_item_id = oim2.order_item_id
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS p
        ON oi.order_id = p.ID
    WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order'
    AND oi.order_item_type = 'line_item'
    AND oim.meta_key = '_product_id'
    AND oim.meta_value = '%d'
    AND oim2.meta_key = 'Ticket Number'
    ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(oim2.meta_value, ' ', 10) DESC

    LIMIT 1
", $product_id ) );
}
```

The code above takes a product id and outputs the meta tag, my issue arose when I realized that when a user buys more than a single quantity the meta value it creates for the 'Ticket Number' key is '10 11' which mysql views as a single string. I tried breaking it apart using SUBSTRING_INDEX as shown above but it wont view any orders past the first.

I need it to view the numbers as individual numbers so if a user buys ten of the item it can recognise the last number as the highest (say 21 22 23 24) and the next user to buy this product the sql query will recognise the 24 from the string as the highest number and make the new items meta be 25.

Here is my function as well if it is of any use, it currently runs but is only working from the meta value of 1 however many of the product is bought:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'action_woocommerce_order_status_completed');

function action_woocommerce_order_status_completed($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
        $get_last_order = get_last_order_id_from_product( 10 );
        if ($get_last_order == null){
            $gen_id_1 = "0";
        } else {
            $get_order_id = implode($get_last_order);
            $lastorder = wc_get_order($get_order_id);
            $lastitem = $lastorder->get_items();

            foreach ($lastitem as $key2 => $value2) {
                $custom_thing = $value2->get_meta('Ticket Number');
            }
            $gen_ids = explode(' ', $custom_thing);
            $gen_id_1 = end($gen_ids);
        }

        $qua = $value->get_quantity();
        for ($x = 1; $x <= $qua; $x++) {
            $gen_id_1++;
            $gen_id_2 .= " $gen_id_1";
        };
        $value->add_meta_data( "Ticket Number", $gen_id_2);
        $value->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a different way, much more easy and efficient to make that work.

When an order change to processing status:

- First, for each order item, I increase the number of tickets sold *(item quantity)*  as an index at the product level (saved/updated as custom product meta data).
- Then for each order item, I generate from the related product index (before updating it) the tickets numbers based on the item quantity, that I save as custom order item meta data.
- And to finish, for each order item, I update the related product "index" adding the quantity sold to the current "index" value.

The code *(commented)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'action_woocommerce_order_status_processing', 10, 2 );
function action_woocommerce_order_status_processing( $order_id, $order ) {
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        // Check that tickets numbers haven't been generated yet for this item
        if( $item->get_meta( "_tickets_number") )
            continue;

        $product     = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Produt Object
        $quantity    = (int) $item->get_quantity(); // Get item quantity

        // Get last ticket sold index from product meta data
        $now_index = (int) $product->get_meta('_tickets_sold');

        $tickets_ids = array(); // Initializing

        // Generate an array of the customer tickets Ids from the product registered index (last ticket ID)
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $quantity; $i++) {
            $tickets_ids[] = $now_index + $i;
        };

        // Save the tickets numbers as order item custom meta data
        $item->update_meta_data( "Tickets numbers", implode('  ', $tickets_ids) ); // Displayed string of tickets numbers on customer orders and emails
        $item->update_meta_data( "_tickets_number", $tickets_ids ); // (Optional) Array of the ticket numbers (Not displayed to the customer)
        $item->save(); // Save item meta data

        // Update the Ticket index for the product (custom meta data)
        $product->update_meta_data('_tickets_sold', $now_index + $quantity );
        $product->save(); // Save product data
    }
    $order->save(); // Save all order data
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

> The `_tickets_number` hidden custom order item meta data is optional and allow you to get the array of tickets, instead of a string of tickets using: `$item->get_meta('_tickets_number');`

---

If you want **a global ticket system** (not at product level) you will use the following instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'action_woocommerce_order_status_processing', 10, 2 );
function action_woocommerce_order_status_processing( $order_id, $order ) {
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        $now_index = (int) get_option( "wc_tickets_number_index"); // Get last ticket number sold (globally)
        $quantity  = (int) $item->get_quantity(); // Get item quantity

        $tickets_ids = array(); // Initializing

        // Generate an array of the customer tickets Ids from the tickets index
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $quantity; $i++) {
            $tickets_ids[] = $now_index + $i;
        };

        // Save the tickets numbers as order item custom meta data
        $item->update_meta_data( "Tickets numbers", implode('  ', $tickets_ids) ); // Displayed string of tickets numbers on customer orders and emails
        $item->update_meta_data( "_tickets_number", $tickets_ids ); // (Optional) Array of the ticket numbers (Not displayed to the customer)
        $item->save(); // Save item meta data

        // Update last ticket number sold (globally)
        update_option( 'wc_tickets_number_index', $now_index + $quantity );
    }
    $order->save(); // Save all order data
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (active theme). It should work.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much. I didn't realise you could actually do that, its my first time developing with woocommerce so I am still finding my feet.